# ¿Cómo poner un limite de clicks en java?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un programa en donde tengo que contar los clicks en un botón y restarlos a un numero ya dado.

Cuando se hayan dado un cierto número de clicks se debe de mostrar un mensaje y dejar de contarlos y restarlos. ¿Cómo puedo poner ese limite?

Este es el código que llevo de uno de los botones (los otros hacen exactamente lo mismo, solo que le restan al numero dado).

```
int clicks;
private void v1OcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    int j=clicks++;
    tOc.setCantAgua(tOc.getCantAgua()-1);
    System.out.println(tOc.getCantAgua());
    if(j==7){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La valvula esta por debajo del 25%, la valvula se cerrara");

        }

}
```

Comment: Deberías poner el código que tienes hecho hasta ahora para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Para incluir el limite incluyendole un if sería suficiente pero no se si lo que quieres es que te indiquemos como incluir el límite o como resolver el problema de los botones??

Comment: @OmarAlami como seria ese limite?

Answer (score 4):

Fuera del evento debes declaras

```
int click_actuales = 1;
int click_maximo = 7;
```

Dentro del click debes hacer

```
if(click_actuales == click_maximo){
   //alerta
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La valvula esta por debajo del 25%, la valvula se cerrara");

}else{
   click_actuales++;
   //codigo restante
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int clicks = 0;
    int maxclicks = 10;

private void v1OcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    clicks++;
    if(clicks =< maxclicks){

    tOc.setCantAgua(tOc.getCantAgua()-1);
    System.out.println(tOc.getCantAgua());
  else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La valvula esta por debajo del 25%, la valvula se cerrara");

        }

}
```

Comment: Podrías comentar un poco lo que haz hecho?

Answer (score 0):

En realidad podrias crear una variable de instancia que sea un contador y cada vez que utilizas un metodo on click actualizas el valor de este, el int clicks lo tenes que declarar al principio de la clase no dentro de initialize, y lo inicializas en 0 en el constructor. pseudocodigo:

```
clase x
{
   int cont;

main(){}

clase x()
{
   cont=0;
   initialize();
}

initialize()
{
    onclick()
    {
        hacesalgo;
        cont++
    }

   onclick2()
    {
        hacesalgo;
        cont++
    }
}

private int cantidadDeClicks()
{return cont;}
```

pd: si usas netBeans podria variar un poco, pero creo que eso es lo que necesitas.